# 'To inspire' vs 'To influence'

Tags: word-usage

> This book inspired me to be a writer vs This book influenced me to be a writer.

How are 'to inspire' and 'to influence'  different from each other? I know they are different, but am not clear on this. Can you please clarify with examples? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

The 'influence someone to do something' construction is reasonably common on the internet, and [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/influence) gives an example:

> *influence 2 verb*: If you influence someone, you use your power to make them agree with
>   you or do what you want.
>
> *He is trying to improperly influence a witness. [VERB noun]*
>
> *The angry crowds could influence the government. [VERB noun]*
>
> ***My dad influenced me to do electronics.*** [VERB noun to-infinitive]

However, the sense involved in OP's example is this more general, less manipulation-orientated one, condensed from the entry at [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/influence):

> *influence* (v) ...  to have an effect on the character, development, or behaviour of someone or something ...

But the same construction [VERB noun to-infinitive] is available with this sense also.

...........

Inspire is defined by [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inspire) as

> *inspire verb* [with object]
>
> 1 Fill (someone) with the urge or ability to do or feel something,
>   especially to do something creative....

and by [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/inspire) as

> to make someone feel that they want to do something and can do it:
>   *His confident leadership inspired his followers.*
>
> [ + to infinitive ] *After her trip to Venezuela, she felt inspired to
>   learn Spanish.* ​
>
> B2 to make someone have a particular strong feeling or reaction:
>
> *She inspires great loyalty among her followers.*
>
> *The captain's heroic effort inspired them with determination.* ​
>
> B2 to give someone an idea for a book, film, product, etc.:
>
> *a piece of music inspired by dolphin sounds*
>
> *The design of the car has inspired many imitations.*

Though with your particular example 'influenced + noun + to-infinitive ...' doesn't carry too much of the 'compel' or slightly sinister flavour (use your power to make them agree), 'inspired + noun + to-infinitive ...' almost always carries an upbeat, healthy, attractive, desirable, and often sense-of-wonder flavour.